# SqlCommand Text multiple queries

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using a list collection and i need to insert each item of my collection inside sql using also parameters.

Here is an example

```
foreach (var item in listCollection)
{
    cmd.CommandText += "Insert into WebAppOrders (id) values (@id)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item.id;
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting an error

> The variable name '@id' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Is there any way which I can make this work?

Comment: Each of your parameters has to have a different name, if you want to execute the command once in the end. Or execute the command for each element, and only change the parameter value instead of adding it.

Comment: i can use an auto increment for this. Is there any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert List(Of Integer) into SQL Server Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200163/insert-listof-integer-into-sql-server-table)

Comment: Anyone which had the same problem?

Comment: Dapper has a solution for this.  If you are a raw ADO.NET user and you start using Dapper, you will never want to go back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple count variable, which you then append to the parameter-name `@id`.

A sample would look like...

Example `Item`-class:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Simulation:

```
var listCollection = new List<Item>() { new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3), new Item(4) };
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("<your connectionstring>"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("", connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    int i = 0; // count
    foreach (var item in listCollection)
    {
        cmd.CommandText += $"Insert into WebAppOrders (id) values (@id{i})"; // add count here
        cmd.Parameters.Add($"@id{i}", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item.Id; // ... and here
        i++;
    }

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thank you oRole. Should be easier to convert it into dataTable and then to make a bulk Insert?

Comment: Hard to say if it's easier, but have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022531/best-way-to-bulk-insert-from-a-c-sharp-datatable). There are multiple ways to do what you want to achieve.